# How to comment if answer is updated

Tags: discussion, comments, edits

I've answered a question.

Topic author commented with some new information.

I am updating my answer and add new comment, to show that answer is updated:

> See my update

But it is too short to be a comment.

So how do you pointing that comment is updated?

*It looks like a stupid question, but I am not native english speaker* :)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the question poster will receive notifications on answer updates, is it?

Comment: really? I've never recieved it. I mean that there was no any new messages in my "inbox"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> See my updated answer.

...is the simplest expansion. If you need to ping the user, also consider a [comment reply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). If you don't know the @ syntax of a comment replies, I suggest reading the link and reviewing it in full.

Other options include, in no particular order:

> Check my update.
>
> I've updated my answer.
>
> My answer has been updated to reflect those changes.
>
> In the interest of consuming a lot more of your time than necessary I present to you this expanded punctuationless run-on comment for the purpose of alerting you that I have produced updated information in the body of my response to address the concerns which you have brought up in your previous comment

Comment: Got it. Thanks, @Grace Note! :)

Comment: @fl00r Speaking of which, I made a tiny update. ♪

Comment: Ok, I'll copypast your last replica to all my updates! With your copyright ofcourse :D.

Comment: +1 because I love consuming time.